# How to make a player move in Android emulator using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a game for Android using libgdx. I want to know what code should I write to make my player move in android? For desktop I have the following code with UP,DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT keys. Please suggest the equivalent code for android. Many thanks.

```
public void update(){
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)&& (shipLocation.y < screenHeight -   ship.getHeight())){
        shipLocation.y=shipLocation.y+5;

    }
```

Comment: not quite understand your question, but almost any internet tutorial can see how, regarding equivalete to android ?. libgdx, he do for you, you just have to write your code on the core, and libgdx makes portability to other plataform

Comment: but if you mean that android has no physical keyboard, as much as usual, is using a stage, and adding actors, I recomiento are looking for youtube, some tutorial

Comment: Hi @AngelAngel Angel. I am able to launch the app on android emulator. But, I am not able to control my player in the emulator. Could you please tell me how can I control it?

Comment: hi, I'm not using the emulator, and not exactly what you mean I leave a link https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=+libgdx I recommend you to watch this channel https://www.youtube.com/user/dermetfan/playlists I think what you are looking for may be in this list https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0Inrp5YMmYEaoh1FBXBJ1J

Answer (score 0):

You have two straightforward choices.

1. **Use touch gestures**

   - You can make the user move in the direction where the user swipes on the screen.
   - Alternatively, you can also give the user a *push* in the direction of vector joining player's current position and the position on screen where user touched.
2. **Create virtual keyboard**

   As you would need only few keys, you can create up, down, left and right keys in a corner of the screen (comfortable for user's hands).

---

Second choice makes your game logic same as desktop, but you will need to have different ui for desktop and android.

Whereas first choice might be more intuitive but may make the game logic a bit complex.

---

Hope this helps.
Good luck.